# Servlet For Loop Causing Http 500 Error

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm in the process of creating a login servlet essentially. I'm not sure why, but my for loop is causing it to display a 500 level error. Any help would would be appreciated. 
The created class is just a basic class with getters and setters.

```
public Login() {
    super();

}

boolean isNameValid;
boolean isPassValid;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
    if (context.getAttribute("HomeworkUsers") == null) {
        ArrayList<CS320User> HomeworkUsers = new ArrayList<CS320User>();
        getServletContext().setAttribute("HomeworkUsers", HomeworkUsers);

        CS320User user1 = new CS320User("John", "Doe", "john@doe.com", "1!");
        CS320User user2 = new CS320User("Joe", "Boxer", "joe@boxer.com",
                "2@");

        HomeworkUsers.add(user1);
        HomeworkUsers.add(user2);

        context.setAttribute("HomeworkUsers", HomeworkUsers);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();

    ArrayList<CS320User> HomeworkUsers = (ArrayList<CS320User>) context
            .getAttribute("HomeworkUsers");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<!doctype html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h3>Login Servlet</h3>");

    out.println("<form action=\"Login\" method=\"post\">");

    out.println("Username: <input type='text' name='Username'/>");
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println("Create Password: <input type='password' name= 'password' /> ");
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println("<label for =\"Remember Me\"> Remember Me");
    out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" id= \"Remember Me\">");
    out.println("</label>");
    out.println("<br/>");

    out.println("<input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' /> ");

    out.println("<br>");

    for (CS320User users : HomeworkUsers) {
        if (users.getEmail().contains(request.getParameter("Username"))
                && users.getPassword().contains(
                        request.getParameter("password"))) {

            out.println(users.getEmail());
            out.println(users.getFirst());
            isNameValid = true;
            isPassValid = true;
        }
    }
    String Username = request.getParameter("Username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    out.println(Username);
    out.println(password);
    out.println(isNameValid);
    out.println(isPassValid);
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (isNameValid == true && isPassValid == true) {
        response.sendRedirect("Welcome");
    }
    doGet(request, response);

}
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, chances are there's an exception in your log. Find it and post it in the question - or delete the question if you can work out the problem based on the exception (which is likely).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are getting a NullPointerException, can you please take your code block (for loop) into a try, catch code block and log the exception that you catched.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't log your exceptions, i mean if you don't handle them you can get 500 errors in runtime as expected.

To prevent this situtation just use `try catch` blocks and handle your exceptions in catch block. (At least log them)

In your code there's only one thing can cause an exception in for loop line and that's the null possibility of your **HomeworkUsers**..

```
ArrayList<CS320User> HomeworkUsers = (ArrayList<CS320User>) context
            .getAttribute("HomeworkUsers");
```

In the code part that i wrote at the top you are getting a context attribute and it can be null. And possibly your solution is checking if it's null or not.

Comment: Thank you. The try, catch seems to make it work now, but I'm having another issue. It would seem my ArrayList is still null. At least I believe it is as it never gets into the if statement as it should.

Comment: Are you sure you added "HomeworkUsers" to your context ?